# How i can assign object key name to be the same name as its value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key

I have this object array:

```
var materials=[{sample:"A21"},{sample:"A22"},{sample:"A23"}];
```

The target is to create an new array replacing "sample" name with its corresponding value...

Result: `var materials2=[{A21:"A21"},{A22:"A22"},{A23:"A23"}];`

is this possible?

i've tried below loop passing key as string but without any luck!

```js
for(i=0; i<materials.length; i++){

materials2.push({"'"+materials[i].sample+"'":materials[i].sample})

}
```

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: The problem was actually accessing property value with the most optimal way. In my case, testing code performance also was important. The other correct approaches already answered did pin-point the subject but @Nina Scholz gave an answer that it was time efficient in ms execution. Since there is no for loop but internal map function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the value with a [computed property name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
var materials = [{ sample: "A21" }, { sample: "A22" }, { sample: "A23" }],
    result = materials.map(({ sample }) => ({ [sample]: sample }));

console.log(result);
```